# Extract data from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I created a dataframe (called df) with few columns (for example 3 columns with the following names: 'data', 'SID' and 'time'). df has only one row. Each cell of the data frame contains a dictionary built as follow:

```
{'column_name': ndarray}
```

For example, the dictionary at the SID column is like this:

```
{'SID': ndarray}
```

I would like to access/extract the ndarrays stored in the dictionaries and assign each one of them to a new variable called after the column name as follows:

```
data = df.at[0, 'data']['data']
SID = df.at[0, 'SID']['SID']
time = df.at[0, 'time']['time']
```

I'm asking for a generic/iterative way to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems a bit 'hacky', but you can use:

```
   for column in df:
     exec(column + '= df.at[0, column][column]')
```

Comment: The created variable is always called column, therefore, in each iteration, the variable is being overridden.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. I changed it